# calling a recursive void within a function with 2 dimensional array as the argument results in Error

Tags: c, function, recursion, void

I am using a function that calls a recursive function with a 2D array as argument but I get this error:

```
In function 'void Rivers(int (*)[1000], int, int)':

cannot convert 'int (**)[1000]' to 'int* (*)[1000]' for argument '1' to 'void Horizontal(int* (*)[1000], int, int, int, int, int*)'
```

Here is the function :

```
void Rivers (int m[1000][1000],int n,int m1)
 {
    int i,j,z=1,cpt;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<m1;j++)
        {
            Horizontal(&m,i,n,m1,j,&cpt);
            printf("river number %d is %d blocks in size\n",z,cpt);
            z++;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the recursive void :

```
void Horizontal(int*m[1000][1000],int i,int n,int m1,int j,int*cpt)
{
    if(i<n && j<m1)
    {
        if(*m[i][j]!=0)
        {
            *m[i][j]=0;
            *cpt++;
            Vertical(&*m,i,n,m1,j,&*cpt);
            Horizontal(&*m,i,n,m1,j-1,&*cpt);
            Horizontal(&*m,i,n,m1,j+1,&*cpt);
        }   
    }

 }
```

Comment: Do you realise that `&m` gives the location of the array/pointer argument on the stack? It's rarely what you want. Without seeing more code I would say its likely you need `int m[1000][1000]` as every function argument, and pass `m`.

Comment: ... also `int cpt` is *uninitialised* yet you are incrementing it indirectly, and the same applies : pass `cpt` not that fancy stuff.

Comment: Weather Vane the values in my matrix are supposed to change when i call Horizontal, wouldn' passing int m[1000][1000] revert all changes after the end of void's execution

Comment: Nope, the array decays to a pointer to its first element. There is only one array: the one owned by the caller that is originally passed, and the functions work on it through pointers.

Comment: but that does mean that all value would change execpt the first one right?

Comment: There is only one array: I does not magically "change back" unless you specifically change it back yourself. Unlike an `int` function argument, of which a *copy* is passed to a function, an array decays to a pointer, and *that* is what is passed to the function. That's why your `&m` is wrong: that's the location of the pointer itself, not the array.

Answer (score 0):

## A pointer to an array isn't an array of pointers.

The type of `m` in `Rivers` is (roughly) `int[1000][1000]`, an array of 1000 arrays of 1000 `int`s.

When you take `&m` the type is (roughly) `int[1000][1000]*`, a pointer to an array of 1000 arrays of 1000 `int`s.

In `Horizontal` the type of `m` is `int*[1000][1000]`, an array of 1000 arrays of 1000 `int*`s. Quite a different type.

## Solution

Don't bother with a pointer as the behavior won't be any different.

Since arrays are not replicated when calling functions, any changes made to `m` in `Horizontal` will affect `m` in `Rivers` without making it a pointer.

```cpp
void Horizontal(int m[1000][1000],int i,int n,int m1,int j,int*cpt);
```

---

Note: Using a `typedef` to name `int[1000][1000]` won't work.  Since the two dimensional arrays aren't kept in the C type system the compiler will throw on the function call with `cannot convert 'int (**)[1000]' to 'int (*)[1000][1000]'` even though they are theoretically the same type.